# ¿A qué se refiere 2830394 en "JAZZTEL Apdo. nº1010 F.D /2830394"?

Tags: números

Quisiera saber a qué se refiere 2830394, que es parte de la dirección de JAZZTEL - [JAZZTEL Apdo. nº1010 F.D /2830394, 28805 Alcalá de Henares Madrid](https://www.ocu.org/reclamar/lista-reclamaciones-publicas/reclamacion-publica?referenceId=CPTES00601165-56). No creo que se refiera al apartado de correos de JAZZTEL, porque ese apartado es nº1010 F.D, ¿no es así? Predonen por hacer unas preguntas tan raras. Si hay existe un foro para hacer la pregunta, ¿será posible “mover” la pregunta a ese foro?  ¡Muchas gracias por su ayuda por adelantado!

Comment: [Franqueo en Destino](https://www.correos.es/es/es/empresas/ecommerce/facilita-las-devoluciones-a-tus-clientes/franqueo-en-destino)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Que tal?. Planteamiento -  A qué se refiere 2830394, parte de la dirección de JAZZTEL

Ese número indica la sucursal de Correos(2830394) en la calle JOSE CABALLERO, 5-7 en ALCALÁ DE HENARES MADRID, donde tendrá un apartado de correos.

Espero te haya ayudado. Saludos
Diego M.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus explicaciones, como siempre! Saludos ~